# Hierarchical grouping in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

How can you manipulate dataframes at multiple levels using groupby? I want to be able to do something like

> data.groupby('col1').groupby(['col2', 'col3']).apply(foo).apply(bar)

Sample data:

```
    user_id year    day hour    events
0   1928375096  2015    196 0   6
1   734605009   2016    32  21  1
2   3333305045  2016    29  5   3
3   698115442   2016    30  7   11
4   685465592   2016    26  12  3
5   485945404   2016    24  10  4
6   73202588    2016    25  3   1
7   4380205067  2016    25  8   1
8   408502597   2016    32  9   1
9   584885164   2016    32  10  3
```

Let's say col1 = user_id, col2 = 'year', col3 = 'day', so we get a number of rows for each user for each day (up to 24). We want to first run foo on events; e.g., `foo(x) = (x-x.mean())/x.std()`, then we want to reduce each user's time series to a scalar with `bar`. The resulting data frame should contain one row per user.

Comment: That's equivalent to `data.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`, no? You'll have more luck if you post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do the functions `foo` and `bar` enter your formulation, @TomAugspurger?

Comment: What are `foo` and `bar`? You haven't defined them or `data` either.

Comment: data is a pandas DataFrame whose columns include col1, col2, col3, etc., foo and bar are arbitrary functions. The question does not depend narrowly on the definition of these functions, hence the placeholder names.

Comment: I suspect it does depend on the functions, e.g. `foo = bar = lambda x: return 1` :) Depending on your problem, `foo` may include a `groupby` within it. It's tough to give a good answer to the general, vauge problem other than saying group by everything at once and then do your operation.

Comment: That's a degenerate case not worthy of discussion. Let's say we want to group by user (col1), then day, time (col2, col3). With the dataframe thus hierarchically partitioned, we want to standardize each user's time series (foo), then calculate a scalar quantity of interest for each user (bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas was not cutting it, so I traded up to blaze, postgres, BigQuery (where the data came from in the first place) before coming back a full circle with pandas's [read_gbq](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq.html) function. I'm begrudgingly writing SQL queries to feed BiqQuery through pandas. I wanted to be able to use DataFrame-style operations, but at least I am skipping the intermediate CSVs.

Comment: I've since learned Google has its own notebook platform with BigQuery support and pandas-like functionality: [DataLab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/). [Example notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/content/datalab/tutorials/BigQuery/BigQuery%20APIs.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

First, think really hard about your problem to ensure that you *actually* need a nested groupby. This is essentially a nested for loop, so performance may become a probably sooner than normal. With that out of the way...

```
In [102]: letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:13])

In [103]: import string

In [104]: letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:13])

In [105]: N = 1000

In [106]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.choice(letters, size=N),
                             'b': np.random.choice(letters, size=N),
                             'c': np.random.choice(letters, N),
                             'd': np.random.randn(N)})
```

The 'a' column is our outermost level of grouping, the "user" in your comment. We group by it ahead of time to precompute it's mean.

```
In [106]: means = df.groupby('a').d.mean()
```

Then we process each group, collecting the results in a temporary list.

```
In [107]: out = []

In [108]: gr = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [108]: for k, v in gr:
              demeaned = v.groupby(('b', 'c')).d.transform(lambda x: x.count() * x) - means.loc[k[0]]
              out.append(demeaned)


In [109]: df['result'] = pd.concat(out)

In [110]: df
Out[110]:
     a  b  c         d    result
0    j  a  a  0.677802  1.107368
1    d  k  e -0.538711  0.032052
2    m  m  f -0.695904 -0.644055
3    m  i  i -0.433602  1.069695
4    m  e  a -2.349382 -0.560345
..  .. .. ..       ...       ...
995  e  e  m -0.626897  1.409865
996  g  m  m  0.434375 -1.402483
997  h  g  j -0.939896  1.440304
998  j  k  m -0.473171 -0.572188
999  d  c  j  0.894530  0.392441

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```